# Long boot time in Honeycomb

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, boot, motorola-xoom

I just got a motorola xoom, love it so far, but it surprises me that the initial boot of the device takes so long (approx 1 minute).  I figured with less RAM than my PC, a less "hoggy" OS (honeycomb vs win 7), and the benefit of a solid state hard drive, that the xoom should be able to boot from off to on-and-functional in like 20 seconds.

does anyone know of a way to decrease the boot time in Honeycomb?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It may be worth noting that the boot time for the nexus one is about a minute.

I think the expected use pattern of Android devices is 'always on', so it's been optimized for everything but boot time.

Comment: Just to add to syntheticbrain's comment: My EVO running cyanogenmod takes just under 2 minutes to get from power-on to home screen.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you're not aware. Hope this is relatedly helpful.
Be sure to NOT press and hold when finishing a session. Just a quick press and it will go into suspend. To resume, another quick press and the screen comes back in about 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

Unless they're something physically defective with your device your options are pretty limited:

1. Install a ROM designed to boot quickly (not sure that any exist)
2. Install a ROM based on a less resource-intensive version of Android (but there's no point in getting a Xoom if you don't run 3.0 IMO)
3. Use an app like [Autostarts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) to prevent some apps from loading upon boot (this probably won't help your boot time before you see the initial lock screen, however)

All three of these options require root access, so if you don't want to root your Xoom then I can't think of anything you can do to decrease your boot time.